# Error when using malloc for a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm in the process of creating a hash table for a homework assignment. I'm using Xcode and it doesn't have any immediate errors but when I try to run it, I get one of those Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when it comes to the function that initially creates the hash table and allocates for it. Specifically the line that uses malloc:

```
Node **ht_create(void)
{

   Node **hashtable[htsize];

   int Node_size = sizeof(Node);

   if( htsize < 1 )
   {
       printf("Error: please enter adequate size for hashtable");
       return NULL;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i<=htsize;i++)
   {
   hashtable[i] = malloc(Node_size);
   }

   if( ( **hashtable)  == NULL )
   {
       printf("Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable");
       return NULL;
   }


    return *hashtable;
}
```

I'm still fairly new to C, I've only started learning it 2 months ago, so if there's a glaring issue and I'm just being an idiot, please bear with me. `htsize` is an integer command line argument that is declared elsewhere. I don't know if it helps, but here is the code that defines my 'Node' struct:

```
struct NodeType
{
    char *key;
    int value;
    struct NodeType *next;
};


typedef struct NodeType Node;
```

Shot in the dark: does it have to do with the fact that I have the pointer in the struct? The `struct NodeType *next;` part?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

edit: I now have it so it allocates for each node in the table with a for loop, but its returning my "Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable" so my hashtable is = NULL now?

Comment: Some people consider it bad practice to typedef structs, by the way. Since you're fairly new to C, you should look into that.

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano Some people, including the C11 specification,  do not consider it bad practice to typedef structs, by the way. You should look into that.

Comment: @chux Yeah, that's why I recommend looking into the issue. I know that a lot of professors (at least at my university) act as if this is just the standard way of doing it.

Comment: maybe you meant to allocate a 2-D array the usual way?

Comment: @BobbySacamano It's part of the assignment to use typedef, but thanks for the tip

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano  typedef-ing **pointers** certainly has its detractors - myself included.  I have no trouble with those typedef-ing structures.  Typedef-ing structures (and pointers) is legal in C.  Arguments pro/con are style issues.  Best to follow your group's style rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully clear on OP's intent, yet I would expect `Node **ht_create(void)` to create and return pointer to an array of `Node *`, so return type `Node **`.  Then the array elements would be initialized to `NULL` as the beginning of each hash table bucket is an empty list.

Tip: easy way to allocate memory.

```
Some_type *pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * array_size);
```

Sample code:

```
Node **ht_create(size_t htsize) { // pass in size
  if (htsize < 1) {
    printf("Error: please enter adequate size for hashtable");
    return NULL;
  }

  //allocate hashtable
  Node **hashtable = malloc(sizeof *hashtable * htsize);
  if (hashtable == NULL) {
    printf("Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable");
    return NULL;
  }

  // Initialize values
  for (size_t i=0; i<htsize; i++) {
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
   }
  return hashtable;
}
```

Comment: You could use calloc or memset instead of the initialization loop, btw.

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano To use `calloc or memset` would rely on `NULL` having an all 0 bit pattern - something not specified by C - although `calloc or memset` would typically be fine. A `for()` loop is more explicit and demonstrative, especially for learners - as we all are.

Comment: @chux I found this in ISO9899 n1256 pg 47 "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
void *, is called a null pointer constant.
55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
to a pointer to any object or function.". Could an architecture have all 0 bit pattern not equal 0? Not playing code golf with beginners is probably a good call though.

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano True that `int *a = NULL;` and `int *b = 0` will both assign the pointers to "null pointers" and `a == b` is true.  Yet printing the 2 pointers may result in different output as a system may have more than 1 null pointer value.  Note: `NULL` is a "null pointer constant".

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano "Could an architecture have all 0 bit pattern not equal 0?" Yes all types, except not `unsigned char`.  Certainly such systems are off the main track - but allowable by the standard.  The big hole is padding bits which can be used by systems in novel ways.  Suggest searching SO - sure it has been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **hashtable = malloc(Node_size * htsize);
```

This is dereferencing hashtable twice, then assigning it to the pointer returned by malloc. You should be assigning the pointer hashtable to the pointer returned by malloc instead.

e.g.

```
     hashtable = malloc(Node_size * htsize);
```

**edit:** I reread your code. You should not be declaring hashtable as an array. The array's storage duration is local; once the function returns, the array is deallocated. You're only returning the first element anyway, so it's probably just a typo.

you should also just `return hashtable`, instead of `return *hashtable`

**update:** You've changed the method to allocate a node for every element of the hashtable array, but you're only returning the first element of that array.

`Node **hashtable[htsize];` should be changed to `Node **hashtable;`
You cannot return an array with automatic storage class, so declaring this as an array seems like a mistake.

Furthermore, you're only returning the first element of this array, so this is causing a memory leak `return *hashtable` is equivalent to return `hashtable[0]`.

I think this is the behavior you're looking for:

```
Node **ht_create(void)
{
   Node **hashtable;

   if(htsize < 1)
   {
       printf("Error: please enter adequate size for hashtable");
       return NULL;
   }

   hashtable = malloc(htsize * sizeof(Node*)) //allocate the array
   if(hashtable  == NULL )
   {
       printf("Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable");
       return NULL;
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < htsize; i++)
   {
       hashtable[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node)); //allocate each node in the array
       if(hashtable[i] == NULL) //you have to null check these too
       {
           printf("Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable");
           return NULL;
       }
   }

   return hashtable; //return the array of node pointers
}
```

You should probably deallocate all the other nodes if an allocation fails, unless you're going to exit the program anyway at that point. You can figure that out however you want, since that's dependent on how you're implementing the rest of your code.

Comment: When I remove the double pointers, I get the compilation error: "Array Type 'Node **[htsize]' is not assignable."

Comment: @chux yeah, I missed that. Declaring that as an array also seems to be a mistake.

Comment: I edited my code a bit to use a for loop to allocate for each node in the table, but I'm now I'm getting my own "Error: could not allocate memory for hashtable" error that I have in the function

Comment: This works as well, thanks man, if I could upvote you both I would, but I don't have enough reputation. I've learned more about malloc and hashtables in the past 30 minutes from you and @chux than I did in an hour and a half lecture. Thanks again.